# Why do two statements result in different result?

Tags: matlab

Matlab seems to have an irritating characteristic. I don't understand why two results from statements is different. The knowledge that implicit declaration of a variable causes it to have double type does not help me understand. Could someone explain how they differ? Here is the code.

```
K>> m = int16(2799)

m =

   2799

K>> n = int16(2800)

n =

   2800

K>> int16( 0.5 * abs(n - m) - 0.5)

ans =

      1

K>> int16 ( 0.5 * abs(2799 - 2800) - 0.5)

ans =

      0

K>>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is the int16 arithmetic:
    abs(n - m)
returns an int16 becaue it is given int16. The result is 1.
The multiplication will return an int16 as well. Therefore, 0.5 * 1 equals 1. (Fractions 0.5 and above are rounded up)

then we have: int16(1 - 0.5) which is again one.

In the other statement, all variables are of type double:

```
int16(0.5 * abs(2799 - 2800) - 0.5)
int16(0.5 * 1 - 0.5)
int16(0.5 - 0.5)
int16(0)
```

Now, why does MATLAB compute 0.5 * x as integer multiplication when x is of class int? <strike>I have no clue :-/</strike>
But I have had problems with integers in MATLAB and tend to avoid them because of that.

---

Okay, the multiplication is done in integers, because [the documentation says so](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/matlab_prog/integers.html#f2-98095). This is opposite to C-like languages (int * double would yield double) but not wrong. And (at least) it is properly defined and documented.

Comment: "Integers or integer arrays and scalar double-precision floating-point numbers. This yields a result that has the same data type as the integer operands."  From http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_prog/integers.html#f2-98095

Comment: Thanks, I always appreciate links to the official documentation. Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: I was writing an answer to the question, but you beat me to it as I got distracted in the docs!  Strange semantics indeed, I much prefer that of C as well.